# serializer increases the query in django rest framwrork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an API that returns the data including ManyToMany relation's data as well, but when I see queries in [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so it's more than 100 queries at the backend which I think is not a good approach, even if the records increases so the queries also get increases. I just want fewer queries so the API can respond faster, is there any way to achieve it?

`models.py`

```py
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='packageroom')
    team_members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='packages')
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'packages'
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'

class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization = OrganizationSerializer(read_only=True)
    organization_type = OrganizationTypeSerializer(read_only=True)
    role = RoleSerializer(read_only=True)
    image = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'organization', 'organization_type',
                  'role', 'email', 'image','image_url', 'contact_number', 'comet_uid']

class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(read_only=True, many=True) # added to fetch tags details
    team_members = UserDetailSerializer(read_only=True, many=True) # added to fetch team members details
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'project', 'tags', 'team_members']
```

`views.py`

```py
  query = Package.objects.filter(project=project_id, is_active=1).prefetch_related('tags', 'team_members').select_related('project', 'account')
  packages = PackageSerializer(query, many=True).data
  return Response(packages)
```

I just want fewer queries so the API can respond faster, is there any way to achieve it?

[image: django toolbar screenshot]

Query result without prefetch and select related:

[image]

Comment: The prefetch and the serializer field should be named "members" not "team_members". Can you share the `TagSerializer` and `UserDetailSerializer`?

Comment: if I'm passing members so it throws me an error that members are not related to select_prefetch.. and also added the required serializers.

Comment: I guess tags and team_members in packageSerializer should be replaced by their related_names defined in package models. And also in query in views.

Comment: when I'm passing related names in the query so it throws me an error `an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()` now I've almost 30 records and the queries are 836 I don't know why this happening.

Comment: @IainShelvington actually it is `team_members`, it was a typo when adding my question but I've updated it

Comment: @ZainKhan this is the way to use realated_names in serializer (to access linked models) and in views (for prefetch and select related), I would suggest reading in detail about prefetch and select related. Bookmarking this question if someone writes a good answer.

Comment: if you can try querying without prefetch and select related and check what the no. of query and timings are.

Comment: @RanuVijay added query result above without prefetch and select related.

Comment: Why are you getting 1065, numbers of query, what's wrong? Is django debug toolbar working properly.

Comment: @RanuVijay because there are too many relations in that API and yes debug toolbar is working fine I've tested it.